# How to pass array data such as A1:A500 into a Excel user defined function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, user-defined-functions, vba

I am attempting to pass a variable array into an excel user-defined function. My Excel VBA is attached below and I 'm hoping I can pass a range such as A1: A100 into the current variable Data and then manipulate it like a normal excel formula.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 Function LowerB_4n_2(inputrange As Range) As Double
 Dim myArray As Variant
 Data = inputrange.Value
 LowerB_4n_2 = Small(Data, (Round((((0.4 * (Count(Data))) - 2)), 0)))
 End Function

 Function UpperB_4n_2(inputrange As Range) As Double
 Dim myArray As Variant
 Data = inputrange.Value
 UpperB_4n_2 = Large(Data, (Round((((0.4 * Count(Data)) - 2)), 0)))
 End Function

 Function Width4n_2(inputrange As Range) As Double
 Dim myArray As Variant
 Data = inputrange.Value
  Width4n_2 = (Large(Data, (Round((((0.4 * Count(Data)) - 2)), 0))) - 
  (Small(Data, (Round((((0.4 * Count(Data)) - 2)), 0)))))

  End Function
```

Comment: Remove `Dim myArray as Variant` (you never use this anyway). and `Data = inputrange.value`. And replace `Data` with `inputrange` in your formula. Also add `Application.WorksheetFunction` in front of `Small` and `large`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Large, Small and Count are all properties of the `Application.WorksheetFunction` therefore they need to have that set as its parent.

Just your first one:

```
 Function LowerB_4n_2(inputrange As Range) As Double
 Dim data() As Variant
 data = inputrange.Value
 LowerB_4n_2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Small(data, (Round((((0.4 * (Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(data))) - 2)), 0)))
 End Function
```

---

As per the comments,

As Large and Small are already streamlined, there is no reason to pass the range value into an array.  we can just refer to the range object in the formulas:

```
 Function LowerB_4n_2(inputrange As Range) As Double
 LowerB_4n_2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Small(inputrange, (Round((((0.4 * (Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(inputrange))) - 2)), 0)))
 End Function

 Function UpperB_4n_2(inputrange As Range) As Double
 UpperB_4n_2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(inputrange, (Round((((0.4 * (Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(inputrange))) - 2)), 0)))
 End Function

 Function Width4n_2(inputrange As Range) As Double
 With Application.WorksheetFunction
     Width4n_2 = .Large(inputrange, (Round((((0.4 * .Count(inputrange)) - 2)), 0)) - .Small(inputrange, (Round((((0.4 * .Count(inputrange)) - 2)), 0))))
 End With
```

Comment: Looks like it works, but I'd definitely scrap the variant array, as suggested in question comments. Among other things, `Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(data)` becomes `inputRange.Count`

Comment: @CallumDA except that `Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(data)` only counts the numeric values and `Range.Count` counts the cells

Comment: Good point. I suspect OP has only numeric values but still agree it's best to leave your answer as is.